# How to make a HTML list appear without the bullets signs using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an HTML list. The browser should see the list's existence and arrange the elements accordingly, however I don't want it to show a bullet next to each element. That is, a normal list appears like this:

> - text A
> - text B
> - text C

I want my list to appear like this:

> text A
>     text B
>     text C

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
ul { list-style: none; }
```

That gets rid of the bullet points. Now you can go ahead and assign styles to space them out like in your example, if that's what you really wanted:

```
li { padding: 5px 0; }
```

If you also don't want the list indented after removing the bullets, it will take another bit, like this:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

If you dont set both margin and padding to 0, it will either look right in FF or IE, but not both

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
list-style:none;
```

in the style for the < ul > tag

Answer (score 3):

*Alternatively*, you can also use a [definition list](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_dl.asp) (`dl`, `dt`, `dd`) without definition terms (`dt` elements).

```
<dl>
    <dd>text A</dd>
    <dd>text B</dd>
    <dd>text C</dd>
</dl>
```

But semantically I think an unordered list (`ul`, `li`) suits your particular purpose better :) So go ahead with *just* a piece of good CSS as explained by Erik.

Comment: Very interesting! Never heard of those tags before.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none"></u>
```

By setting the style type to none the bullets will not show.

Answer (score -1):

list-style-type: upper-roman;